# Proof of extrema of $\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

I need to find the values of $a$ at which $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(a+h)-\sin(a)}{h} = 0.$$ I know that this means that we are looking for the values of $a$ at which $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin x=0$, or $\cos x=0$.
I also know from calculus 1 that a should equal $\dots,\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}, \dots$

However, I can't figure out how I can show this using "real-analysis" level definitions and theorems. Do I need to use the definition of limits to show that $\frac{\sin(a+h)-\sin(a)}{h} \to 0$? How do I use that to find the appropriate values of $a$?

Comment: It might help us if you told us your definition of sine.

Comment: My definition of sin? I'm not sure if I understand the request.

Comment: How are you defining the sine function? That will impact how the proof is given.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question at all, but sinx is defined for all real numbers.

Comment: You're interested in a "real analysis" level proof. That means you have to start with with a rigorous definition of the sine function. So again I ask, what _is_ the sine function? Are you defining it as a power series? In terms of the complex exponential? As the solution of a differential equation?

Comment: Oh wow. I'm really sorry for my stupidity, but I don't think that we've gotten quite to that level yet in my analysis class.

Comment: In that case, I would say that the traditional proof that the cosine is the derivative of sine is rigorous enough until you have a formal definition of the sine function.

Comment: Would it be okay although we have not yet formally gone over the power rule in our course yet?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The power rule doesn't play a role in proving that the derivative of sine is cosine. I assume you're just using the geometric definition of "opposite over hypotenuse", so have you seen the geometric proof based on the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. The power rule wouldn't matter for the derivative of sin.
The geometric proof based on the squeeze theorem doesn't sound familiar, but I do know the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Hm. Have you seen a proof that the derivative of the sine is cosine at all? Normally such a proof is given in calculus before real analysis.

Comment: Ahhh yes. I do remember that. I guess I could use that proof to show that the derivative of sinx is cosx and then show the values of a at which cosx=0?
Thank you so much for your guidance!